# PHP replace hyphen with space

Tags: php, html

So, I have a piece of code I am using in most of my pages which sets the page title as the file name. This is because I don't want to have to change the title each time I create a new page.

This all works fine, except I don't want to have spaces (or rather, %20) being shown in the url when the file name contains spaces. I'd much rather have hyphens in place of the spaces, as it looks cleaner to the user. However, this means PHP will set the page title also with hyphens instead of spaces, which, frankly, looks ugly.

Is there a way I can rewrite this code to replace the hyphens with spaces?

The code:

```
<?php
echo '<title>';
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
echo ucfirst($path_parts['filename']);
echo " - Tom's basic Web Tutz";
echo '</title>';
?>
```

Comment: Please [make use of the search bar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+replace) before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, I did search for about 20 minutes but it honestly never came up :(

Comment: How strange, the phrase `php replace` gives me 65k results.

Comment: Well, obviously I got results, but I never saw the question mentioned above. Although, to be fair, I haven't slept in days. I am just coming to a stand stil

Comment: Reminds me of making flash games in highschool ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the `-` with a space.

```
<?php
echo '<title>';
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
echo ucfirst(str_replace('-', ' ', $path_parts['filename']));
echo " - Tom's basic Web Tutz";
echo '</title>';
?>
```

Comment: Ah, yes, obviously! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode` adn `explode` for this

```
$string = "the string";
$arr = explode("string to replace",$string);
$string = implode("string to add ",$arr);
echo $string;
```